# How to set the thread_name in struct per_thread_data in log4cplus

Tags: logging, log4cplus

I use log4cplus-1.1.2 in Linux. It seems that no way to set `thread_name` and `thread_name2` in `struct per_thread_data`.

The definition of `struct per_thread_data` as followed in file internal.h at line 111-130:

```cpp
//! Per thread data.
struct per_thread_data
{
    per_thread_data ();
    ~per_thread_data ();

    tostringstream macros_oss;
    tostringstream layout_oss;
    DiagnosticContextStack ndc_dcs;
    MappedDiagnosticContextMap mdc_map;
    log4cplus::tstring thread_name;
    log4cplus::tstring thread_name2;
    gft_scratch_pad gft_sp;
    appender_sratch_pad appender_sp;
    log4cplus::tstring faa_str;
    log4cplus::tstring ll_str;
    spi::InternalLoggingEvent forced_log_ev;
    std::FILE * fnull;
    log4cplus::helpers::snprintf_buf snprintf_buf;
};
```

log4cplus will allocate such struct for each thread for logging.

Call `LOG4CPLUS_EXPORT log4cplus::tstring const & getCurrentThreadName()` and `LOG4CPLUS_EXPORT log4cplus::tstring const & getCurrentThreadName2()` are the only way to access `thread_name` and `thread_name2` respectively. However, the user cannot modify they values.

Comment: It seems to be better that the return type of `getCurrentThreadName()` and `getCurrentThreadName2()` should not be `const`, and the users can modify them.

Comment: That is an interesting idea. If you implement a reasonable change/patch with this feature, I will include it in log4cplus. Instead of using non-const reference, implement it as a `setCurrentThreadName{,2}()`.

Comment: OK! I will try it. @VáclavZeman

Comment: It would be best if you forked [log4cplus Github](https://github.com/log4cplus/log4cplus) and provided your patch as a pull request there.

Answer (score 0):

Setting thread name in log4cplus is now possible, since log4cplus 1.1.3-RC4 and since log4cplus 1.2.0-RC3 by using `log4cplus::thread::setCurrentThreadName()` and `log4cplus::thread::setCurrentThreadName2()`.